# How to solve the problem in Javascript code to generate de Bruijn sequences?

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm

I am trying to convert some C code to JavaScript. I chose one of the simplest rules (PCR4) and removed all irrelevant parts. The goal is to generate a particular de Bruijn sequence for a particular value of `n`. For example, if `n = 6`, the output should be

```
 0000001111110110100100110111010101100101000101111001110001100001
```

I found the C source code here: http://www.combos.org/bruijn:

```c
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Joe Sawada, Aaron Williams, Dennis Wong, and Daniel Gabric
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Listings of 7 de Bruijn sequences via O(n) time and space successor rules
// Four of the rules are based on the PCR and three are based on the CCR
//
// Research by Joe Sawada, Aaron Williams, Dennis Wong, and Daniel Gabric
// Programmed by Joe Sawada, Sept. 2015 - June 2016.
// Some minor modifications for usage within the Combinatorial Object Server
// by Torsten Muetze.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

// =====================
// Test if a[1..n] = 0^n
// =====================
int Zeros(int a[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (a[i] == 1) return 0;
    return 1;
}
// =============================
// Test if b[1..n] is a necklace
// =============================
int IsNecklace(int b[], int n) {
    int i, p=1;

    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        if (b[i-p] > b[i]) return 0;
        if (b[i-p] < b[i]) p = i;
    }
    if (n % p != 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}
// ===========================================
// Necklace Successor Rules
// ===========================================
int Granddaddy(int a[], int n) {
    int i,j,b[MAX];
    
    j = 2;
    while (j<=n && a[j] == 1) j++;
    for (i=j; i<=n; i++) b[i-j+1] = a[i];
    b[n-j+2] = 0;
    for (i=2; i<j; i++) b[n-j+i+1] = a[i];
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,n)) return 1-a[1];
    return a[1];
}
// -------------------------------
int Grandmama(int a[], int n) {
    int i,j,k,b[MAX];
    
    j = 1;
    while (j<n && a[n-j+1] == 0) b[j++] = 0;
    b[j] = 1;
    k = 2;
    for (i=j+1; i<=n; i++) b[i] = a[k++];
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,n)) return 1-a[1];
    return a[1];
}
// -------------------------------
int PCR3(int a[], int n) {
    int i,b[MAX];
    
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) b[i] = a[i+1];
    b[n] = 1;
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,n)) return 1-a[1];
    return a[1];
}
// -------------------------------
int PCR4(int a[], int n) {
    int i,b[MAX];
    
    b[1] = 0;
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) b[i] = a[i];
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,n)) return 1-a[1];
    return a[1];
}
// ===========================================
// Co-necklace Successor Rules
// ===========================================
int CCR1(int a[], int n) {
    int i,j,b[MAX],c=1;
    
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) if (a[i] == 0) break;
    for (j=i; j<=n; j++) b[c++] = a[j];
    b[c++] = 1;
    for (j=2; j<i; j++)  b[c++] = 1-a[j];
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) b[n+i] = 1-b[i];

    if (IsNecklace(b,2*n)) return a[1];
    return 1-a[1];
}
// -------------------------------
int CCR2(int a[], int n) {
    int i,j,b[MAX],c=1;
    
    i = n;
    while(a[i] == 0 && i >=1) i--;
    if(i == 0) i = n;
    for (j=i+1; j<=n; j++) b[c++] = 0;
    b[c++] = 1;
    for (j=2; j<=i; j++) b[c++] = 1-a[j];
    for (j=1; j<=n; j++) b[n+j] = 1-b[j];
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,2*n)) return a[1];
    return 1-a[1];
}
// -------------------------------
int CCR3(int a[], int n) {
    int i,b[MAX];
    
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) b[i] = a[i+1];
    b[n] = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) b[n+i] = 1-b[i];
    
    if (IsNecklace(b,2*n) && !Zeros(b,n)) return a[1];
    return 1-a[1];
}
// =====================================================================
// Generate de Bruijn sequences by iteratively applying a successor rule
// =====================================================================
void DB(int rule, int n) {
    int i, new_bit, a[MAX];

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) a[i] = 0;   // First n bits
    do {
        printf("%d", a[1]);
        switch(rule) {
            case 1: new_bit = Granddaddy(a,n); break;
            case 2: new_bit = Grandmama(a,n); break;
            case 3: new_bit = PCR3(a,n); break;
            case 4: new_bit = PCR4(a,n); break;
            case 5: new_bit = CCR1(a,n); break;
            case 6: new_bit = CCR2(a,n); break;
            case 7: new_bit = CCR3(a,n); break;
            default: break;
        }
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[n] = new_bit;
    } while (!Zeros(a,n));
    printf("\n");
}
// -------------------------------
void usage() {
    printf("Usage: db1 [n] [rule] (n>=1, 1<=rule<=7)\n");
}
// -------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, n, rule;
     
    if (argc < 3) {
      usage();
      return 1;
    }
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &rule);
    if ((rule < 1) || (rule > 7) || (n < 1)) {
      usage();
      return 1;
    }
    DB(rule, n);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code in Javascript:

```js
function Zeros(a, n) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 1) {
            return 0
        }
    };
    return 1;
};

function IsNecklace(b, n) {
    var i, p = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (b[i - p] > b[i]) {
            return 0
        };
        if (b[i - p] < b[i]) {
            p = i
        };
    }
    if (n % p !== 0) {
        return 0
    };
    return 1;
};

function PCR4(a, n) {
    var i, b = new Array(a.length);
    b[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i]
    };
    if (IsNecklace(b, n)) {
        return 1 - a[0]
    };
    return a[0];
};

function DB(n) {
    var i, new_bit, a = [];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0
    };
    do {
        new_bit = PCR4(a, n);
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
        };
        a[n - 1] = new_bit;
    } while (!Zeros(a, n));
    return a
}

console.log(DB(6));
```

But it does not work: the output is nothing but an array of zeros (instead of an array of zeros and ones corresponding to the correct output for a given n) -- no matter whether I use `DB(6)` or `DB(64)`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please define "does not work". Incorrect output? No output? Errors?

Comment: @Jayce444: "does not work" means that the output is nothing but an array of zeros (instead of an array of zeros and ones corresponding to the correct output for a given `n`).

Comment: I did not look at the c source, but in for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
        }; when i is n-1, won't that be looking at a[n] which is out of bounds? I may be missing something. Just trying to help.

Comment: @JeremyKahan: Thanks! I didn't notice it. I have fixed this, but it did not help to obtain the correct output...

Comment: Wondering about (n % p !== 0) which would fail if 0 and the result of the mod were different types. (n % p != 0) might be better (and is what is in the original source).

Comment: @JeremyKahan: Yes, I know. I tested both `!=` and `!==` before asking the question, but it does not seem to change anything in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that in `DB` you `return a`. If you look at the condition of the loop just above that return, you'll see that this loop exits when `a` consists only of zeroes. So it is no wonder you only get zeroes in the output.

In the C-code you referred to, `DB` does not return anything. It prints. So if you want to make this a function that *returns* the result, you should collect the output in a variable at the same spot as where the C-code prints. This could be a JavaScript string, and then the function should return that string:

```js
function DB(n) {
    var i, new_bit, a = [], output = ""; // Variable for collecting output
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0
    };
    do {
        output += a[0]; // <--- collect
        new_bit = PCR4(a, n);
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
        };
        a[n - 1] = new_bit;
    } while (!Zeros(a, n));
    return output; // <--- return collected characters
}
```

A second problem occurs in `IsNecklace`, where you missed an aspect while converting the C-code to be 0-index-based:

This:

```
p = i
```

Should be:

```
p = i + 1
```

...because `i` is now a zero-based index, while `p` is a *difference* between indexes. `p` should get the same values, independent on which indexing you use.

#### Some JavaScript shortcuts

Although an almost literal translation of the code works, you might as well use some of the more powerful functions that JavaScript offers, like `Array#fill`, `Array#includes`, `Array#shift`, `Array#push`, `Array.from`, ...

Here is what that could look like:

```js
function isNecklace(b) {
    let p = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i - p] > b[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (b[i - p] < b[i]) {
            p = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return +!(b.length % p);
};

function pcr4(a) {
    let b = Array.from(a);
    b[0] = 0;
    return a[0] ^ isNecklace(b);
};

function DB(n) {
    let output = "";
    let a = Array(n).fill(0);
    do {
        output += a[0];
        let new_bit = pcr4(a);
        a.shift();
        a.push(new_bit);
    } while (a.includes(1));
    return output;
}

console.log(DB(6));
```